# MySql - INNER JOIN on two tables - duplicate results

Tags: mysql, inner-join, duplicate-data

New to JOIN, and have looked at many answers here on stackoverflow... I think I am going about this the wrong way - any help much appreciated!

I have two tables I want to join from two different databases:

**database: ered**
**table: 14jan**

```
dev             datepicker
--------------------------
Ananda          2014-02-01
Anita           2014-02-01 
Syamasundari    2014-02-01
Ananda          2014-03-04
Anita           2014-03-04 
Syamasundari    2014-03-04
Ananda          2014-05-06
Anita           2014-05-06 
Syamasundari    2014-05-06
```

**database: calpaid**
**table: bookings_items**

```
id      desc_en 
---------------
149     Ananda 
250     Anita 
427     Syamasundari
```

The results I would like..and expected:

**table: bookings (id is auto-incremented)**

```
id  id_item     the_date    id_state    id_booking
--------------------------------------------------
1   149         2014-02-01  ok          ok
2   149         2014-03-04  ok          ok
3   149         2014-05-06  ok          ok
4   250         2014-02-01  ok          ok
5   250         2014-03-04  ok          ok
6   250         2014-05-06  ok          ok
7   427         2014-02-01  ok          ok
8   427         2014-03-04  ok          ok
9   427         2014-05-06  ok          ok
```

The query I am using returns duplicate results:

**QUERY**

```
INSERT INTO calpaid.bookings (id,id_item,the_date,id_state,id_booking)
SELECT '$id', b.id, e.datepicker, '$id_state', '$id_booking'
FROM ered.14jan e 
INNER JOIN
     calpaid.bookings_items b
     ON e.dev = b.desc_en
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?
I have experimented a bit with GROUP and also DISTINCT, but with no luck.

Thanks
Caitanya

Comment: Those are not duplicate results.  Look at the date and id columns and you will see that they are different.

Comment: if you noticed that (and that's not what is wanted), then is there something else that we're missing or you want changed to suit?

Comment: Thanks Gordon,somehow the post does not show that the auto-incremented numbers 1-9... I'll try edit that now

Comment: ok, thats edited now.... when I say "duplicate results" I mean duplicate results in all columns... obviously id will be unique due to auto-increment

Comment: What about combination of the_date and id_item(They are not unique ) ?

Comment: Vinit, the results I am getting are displayed 1-9 and then repeated again with auto-increment of 10 - 18

Answer (score 0):

If i'm correct the thing you want this:

```
INSERT INTO calpaid.bookings (id,id_item,the_date,id_state,id_booking)
SELECT '$id', b.id, e.datepicker, '$id_state', '$id_booking'
FROM ered.14jan e 
INNER JOIN
     calpaid.bookings_items b
     ON e.dev = b.desc_en 
group by id_item
```

Comment: returns this message:
Error adding data into database: Unknown column 'id_item' in 'group statement'

Answer (score 0):

You are only sort of going about it the wrong way.  What you probably want is:

```
INSERT INTO calpaid.bookings(id_item, the_date, id_state, id_booking)
    SELECT  b.id, e.datepicker, '$id_state', '$id_booking'
    FROM ered.14jan e INNER JOIN
         calpaid.bookings_items b
         ON e.dev = b.desc_en ;
```

That is, leave `id` out of the `insert` all together.  This assumes that `calpaid.bookings(id)` is auto-incremented.  If it is not, you should design the table so the id is an auto-incremented primary key.  Then, when you insert a value into the field, it automatically increments.

If that didn't suit you for some reason, you could use a variable instead:

```
INSERT INTO calpaid.bookings(id, id_item, the_date, id_state, id_booking)
    SELECT  (@rn := @rn + 1), b.id, e.datepicker, '$id_state', '$id_booking'
    FROM ered.14jan e INNER JOIN
         calpaid.bookings_items b
         ON e.dev = b.desc_en CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon,  id  already is auto-incremated primary key.
  
tried your suggestion above...   
get a set of rows auto-incrementd 1-9, thats fine, 
but then the rows are repeated again with auto-incremtions from 10-18

Comment: @CaitanyaCandradas . . . That is correct behavior.  What do you want the query to do?

Comment: The problem is the results are as follows:

`id  id_item     the_date    id_state    id_booking

8   427         2014-03-04  ok          ok

9   427         2014-05-06  ok          ok
...
17   427         2014-03-04  ok          ok

18   427         2014-05-06  ok          ok
`

Comment: Solved this problem... you was right, the query was correct and showing the correct behavior... when I ran it in phpmyadmin it returned the right amount of rows
My problem was rather in the php script that used.
Thanks for confirming that the query is correct.